# Calculating a Point's X position on Catenary Curve, given pos Y

Tags: trigonometry, conic-sections

How can I calculate for the X coordinate given the Y value of the position? In this example the Y position is -3 units, as seen in the image below.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenary

We know the **Span = 100** (width) and the **Sag = -10** (height). I'm not sure where to begin in solving for the two points X position marked yellow in the image below.

If for any reason it's easier to solve for the X position on a **Parabola** rather than a **Catenary** I'm fine with that, they are similar enough it would be ok.

[image]

Comment: Have you tired using the values you know and the general form of the catenary curve? i.e. when $x$ is $0$, $y$ is $-10$, or when $x$ is $50$, $y$ is $0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a parabola, this isn't hard at all. The parabola equation is then 
$$
y = -10 + 10 \left (\frac{x}{50}\right)^2
$$

To solve for $y= -3$, you write
\begin{align}
-3 &= -10 + 10 \left (\frac{x}{50}\right)^2\\
7 &=  10 \left (\frac{x}{50}\right)^2\\
\frac{7}{10} &=  \left (\frac{x}{50}\right)^2\\
\sqrt{\frac{7}{10}} &=  \pm \frac{x}{50}\\
50 \sqrt{\frac{7}{10}} &=  \pm x\\
\pm 50 \sqrt{\frac{7}{10}} &=  x
\end{align}
giving $x \approx \pm 41.83.$